# Visual Studio и remote build на Linux

Tags: windows, gcc, gdb, visual-studio, linux

Есть проект под линукс, но по корпоративным причинам нет возможности разрабатывать его в линуксе и приходится пользоваться visual studio.

нужно устроить удаленную сборку на сервере под линуксом с помощью gcc и отладку gdb. 
Пробовал VisualGDB - не подходит, т.к. не умеет встраиваться в уже готовые проекты и не совсем корректно работает местами.
На данный момент мучаюс с WinGDB. Но пока результатов особых нет.

Какие решения еще могут быть? Может кто сталкивался?

P.S. Виртуалки и прочее не предлагать - корпоративная политика запрещает. MinGW тоже отпадает.

Comment: а нужна ли удаленная сборка? может проще открыть окошко терминала (например, используя putty) и писать себе код. Сборку делать с помощью make/аналогов. А код писать с помощью vim/emacs/другой любимый редактор.

А разрабатывать с помощью visual studio под линукс... это особый вид развлечения.

Comment: Чего только на свете не бывает... Что же это за корпоративная политика такая?

Comment: А X-window на клиенте (Вашей PC) тоже запрещена корпоративной политикой?

Comment: @FeliX А что разрешает сервер? gcc, gdb, ssh -- правильно? На Вашей стороне  putty... Этого хватает. Нужна ide? Следующий вопрос -- сервер предоставляет Emacs/XEmacs? если да -- так отлаживайтесь под ним -- вполне себе крутая IDE и уж указатель на строку в соседнем окне всяко изобразит.

Comment: Конечно все это уже было сделано и предложено. В команде 30+ человек и объяснять всем как это и что не охото, а да и они не хотят. Самое главное требование - нормальный отладчик. В идеале - gdb интегрированный в студию.

Вот такие бывают извращения в корпорациях :(

Comment: В конце 90х был у меня один заочно знакомый, который в фидошной ru.os.cmp постоянно защищал решения MS. В начале нулевых в ru.gnu этот товарищ написал, что лучший отладчик -- gdb+emacs. Может надо просто продемонстрировать, как это всё работает (кто Сергея научил пользоваться emacs'ом и gdb, я не знаю. Но такие заявления вместо прежних "столлмановские обсирки"...)

Answer (score 1):

Все таки попробуйте, Kubuntu+KDevelop на локальной машине.
Я недавно один свой проект благополучно перенес с VS на разработку в такой среде. 
KDevelop мне нравится наличием нормального показа коллекций в отладчике и автокомплитом в редакторе.

Если корпоративные правила запрещают виртуалки... ну что же, попробуйте попросить для каждого члена команды по доп. ноутбуку для девелопмента под линуксом. Возможно, после этого корпоративная политика позитивно изменится в пользу freeware VM типа VirtualBox.

Еще вариант (который, кстати, успешно используется мной как минимум в 2-х проектах) - если есть возможность - делать кроссплатформенное приложение, которое будет работать и в винде и под линуксом. Тогда основную часть кода можно отдебажить под студией. А на линуксе достаточно будет консоли, компилятора и иногда gdb чтобы анализировать coredump-ы.

Upd. Oracle Studio умеет делать нечто подобное http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18659_01/html/821-2125/studioidetut.html#gkckf

Answer (score -1):

Используй Cmake: для написания проекта VS с последующей сборкой и тестированием на linux

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше мнение?